# If $f$ has $f''(x) > 0$ for $x\in[a,b]$ then it has $y$-values $\geq$ to those of any tangent line drawn to it from a point in that interval.

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I am self studying Calculus and I found this problem in a textbook that I am using. I think this problem should be solvable using Calculus 1 derivatives. (It is from the applications of derivatives section)

Question:

Prove that if a twice differentiable function $f$ has $f''(x) > 0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ then – over that same interval – it has $y$-values greater than or equal to those of any tangent line drawn to it from a point in that interval. Show that a function with $f''(x) > 0$ everywhere cannot always be negative.

My thoughts so far:

I know how to do the second part of the question when it asks me to show how a function with $f''(x) > 0$ can not always be negative. But, I have no idea how to approach the first part.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let the equation of a line tangent to $f$ at some $c \in [a,b]$ be denoted by:
$$ g(x):= f'(c) (x-c) + f(c)$$
Let's define the (signed) distance between $f$ and the tangent line $g$ by:
$$ h(x) := f(x) - g(x) $$
Your problem is equivalent to showing that $h(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Firstly, notice that $h(c) = 0$. We will show that this is actually a local minimum. Observe that
$$\begin{align} h'(x) &= f'(x) - g'(x)\\
&= f'(x) - f'(c)\\
\Rightarrow h'(c) &= 0
\end{align}$$
so that $h$ has a critical point at $x = c$. For the second derivative,
$$\begin{align}
h''(x) &= f''(x) - g''(x)\\
&= f''(x) - 0 > 0
\end{align}$$
Thus, $h(c)$ is a local minimum so that $h(x) \ge 0$ for all other values of $x \in [a,b]$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Often, if you want to prove something, it's helpful to assume its negation is true and see if that leads to absurdity. This is called proof by contradiction. Let's try it.

For a contradiction, assume for some $ c \in [a,b]$ that that the tangent at $f(c)$, call it $g(x)$, does in fact intersect $f(x)$ elsewhere, at $d \in [a,b]$.

Now, since $f(x)$ is continuous (since it is differentiable) on $[c,d]$, and differentiable on $(c,d)$, invoke the mean value theorem, which states that for some $e \in (c,d)$, $f'(e) = \frac{f(d)-f(c)}{d-c}$. So somewhere the slope at $e$ is the same as the slope of the line (secant) between $f(c)$ and $f(d)$.

But the secant has the slope of $f'(c)$. And we are told that $f''(x) > 0$, meaning that for $c<e$, $f'(c)<f'(e)$. But we have $c<e$ and $f'c)=f'(e)$. Which is impossible.

Therefore f(x) never intersects the tangent over $[a,b]$.